# Combinations of two arrays

Tags: java, arrays, combinations

I have two integer arrays of same size:  a and b. They both contain n amount of elements.

Let's say:

```
a = {1, 3, 5}, b = {2, 3, 4}
```

There's a function that outputs an integer based on the two numbers. The algorithm of how the integer is calculated is random. But the function takes TWO integers.

What the problem asks for is the largest integer produced by combining one element from a and one element from b until all elements are used (sum). So I need to find a way to list the combinations of a and b as such: ..f(x,y) = function(x,y)

```
a and b = f(1,2) + f(3,3) + f(5,4)  or
          f(1,2) + f(3,4) + f(5,3)  or
          f(1,3) + f(3,2) + f(5,4)  or
          f(1,3) + f(3,4) + f(5,2)  ... and so on which produces n*(n-1) results.
```

I'm just stuck on how to combine these and find the largest sum. My solution was to run through 3 loops and store each result into an array, and output the largest value of them. However, I'm  having trouble making an array to do such. Can someone help me out please?

Thank you.

-------------- E D I T ---------------------------

I don't need to find the sum of TWO elements. 
Let's say I have two arrays:

```
a = {1, 2, 3}, b = {5, 3, 6}
```

I need to find the greatest sum these two arrays after each of these elements are combined and processed in a function. Let's make a random function:

```
public static int randomFunc(int x, int y){
       return x%(y+1);
}
```

Then, these are the possible outputs:

```
randomFunc(a[0], b[0]) + randomFunc(a[1], b[1]) + randomFunc(a[2], b[2]) = 6
randomFunc(a[0], b[0]) + randomFunc(a[1], b[2]) + randomFunc(a[2], b[1]) = 6
randomFunc(a[0], b[1]) + randomFunc(a[1], b[0]) + randomFunc(a[2], b[2]) = 6
randomFunc(a[0], b[1]) + randomFunc(a[1], b[2]) + randomFunc(a[2], b[0]) = 6
randomFunc(a[0], b[2]) + randomFunc(a[1], b[0]) + randomFunc(a[2], b[1]) = 6
randomFunc(a[0], b[2]) + randomFunc(a[1], b[1]) + randomFunc(a[2], b[0]) = 6
These answers are the same but you get the point. But out of these "outputs", it should 
output the greatest one.
```

Comment: Provide the code with your attempt to explain what's going wrong there.

Comment: 2 for loops will be enough.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a quick implementation I wrote up of two for-each loops to calculate the greatest sum.

```
 public static void main(String []args){

    int greatestSum = 0;
    int[] a = {1, 3, 5};
    int[] b = {2, 3, 4};

    for(int i : a) {
        for(int j : b) {
            if ((i+j) > greatestSum)
                greatestSum = i+j;
        }
    }

    System.out.println(greatestSum);
 }
```

Comment: This isn't what i was looking for! You take the greatest sum of 2 elements, but I have to find the greatest COMBINATION of sums.

Answer (score 0):

```
 You can use this as a reference code. Can be tweaked a lot but you can get an idea.
    List a = new ArrayList();
    a.add(1);
    a.add(3);
    a.add(6);

    List b = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    b.add(4);
    b.add(2);
    b.add(7);


    Hashtable result = new Hashtable<String,Integer>();
    result.put("SUM",0);
    for(int i=0;i<a.size();i++) {
        for(int j=0;j<b.size();j++) {
            int sum = ((Integer) a.get(i) + (Integer)b.get(j));
        if( sum > (Integer) result.get("SUM")) {
            result.put("SUM",sum);
            result.put("PAIRA",a.get(i));
            result.put("PAIRB",b.get(j));
        }
        }
    }
    System.out.println("Max Sum ="+result.get("SUM"));
    System.out.println("PAIR = "+result.get("PAIRA") +" , "+result.get("PAIRB"));
```